# How to open Github for Windows' Git Shell on right click?

Tags: git, powershell, github-for-windows

How can I add the option to `"open a Git Shell here"` on right-clicking on a repo folder? So that I don't have to open `Github for Windows` and right click on the repo's name and choose `"open a shell here"`?

I can open a normal PowerShell or cmd via right click, but they lack the add-ons like `posh-git` that the `Git Shell` of `Github for Windows` provides

Comment: This is not a programming question, so is likely to get close. Anyhow, try TortoiseGit.

Comment: posh-git? that's git with attitude!

Comment: While this is not specifically about programming, we have 9000 questions tagged [PowerShell], and opening a GitHub PowerShell in an arbitrary folder seems like it would be the kind of thing progammers want to know how to do.

Comment: Isn't there a way to move it to the Super User stack exchange? I also think this is a relevant question, but probably better there.

Answer (score 2):

Try `Shift`+`Right Click` > `Open shell here`.  With the default installation, git should add this option to the extended context menu in Windows Explorer.